# Does Solr support customize FunctionQuery?

Tags: lucene, solr

solr wiki FunctionQuery page shows solr supports sort by function

```
Sort By Function

<!> Solr3.1

It is now possible to sort the results by the output of a function. For instance, if an application wanted to sort by distance, it could do:

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&sort=dist(2, point1, point2) desc
```

but all solr available functions did not suit my case, so does solr support customize functionquery?

If solr supports, please show me some examples.
thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add own/customized functionQuerys to solr.
For that, you have to expand the source code.

For an example look at this:
http://www.supermind.org/blog/756/how-to-write-a-custom-solr-functionquery

Answer (score 1):

There have been some changes in writing custom functions for solr 4. Check out http://glennengstrand.info/solr/customize for a summary of what to sub class and why.